# Magento community Home page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, home

How to customize homepage change the background color and add product to home page in magento community

Comment: you want to display particular category product or what?

Comment: I want to customized my home page by adding category products and change the background colour to Green or something more of fruit and vegetable store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for Display particular category on home page Add `CMS -> Manage pages->Home page`

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="YOUR_CATEGORY" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Here **YOUR_CATEGORY** add your category ID

For change Background color share your url i will tell give you the code

Comment: Am building my site on localhost.

Comment: Ok try with this first

Comment: Have try the home page stuff.  It is not showing the products.  Pls how to i know my category_id?

Comment: go manage category click category name in top it shows category id you can use that